# how to fill background on sliding the range slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```js
    function myValue(val) {
    document.getElementById('inputVal').innerHTML=val; 
}
```

```css
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 1.3px;
  border: 0.2px solid #010101;
}

input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000, 0px 0px 1px #0d0d0d;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  height: 36px;
  width: 16px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: #e7ffff;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin-top: -5px;
}

input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 8.4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000, 0px 0px 1px #0d0d0d;
  background: #3071a9;
  border-radius: 1.3px;
  border: 0.2px solid #010101;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<div>
<input type = "range" min = "10" max = "100" step = "1" onchange="myValue(this.value);" oninput="myValue(this.value)">
<div id = "inputVal"></div>
</div>
<body>
</html>
```

I am using simple input range by html. i can modify track and thumb But i want to fill color of track on moving thumb in forward direction and remove color on moving backside. How i can do this ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [input type range css - background color](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22295498/input-type-range-css-background-color)

Comment: Sorry, i tried to find the solution before but unable to get the solutions. How i can make it  different or what to do next ?

Comment: some html elements such as select tag and the slider have standard looks despite you can use some css tricks on them. I would suggest a Jquery slider widget for quick implementation or pure javascript to create a slider widget from scratch to suit your design and specs that a normal slider doesn't have (this may be challenging)..go with the Jquery option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the JQuery Slider to get the same result.

### CSS:

```
#red {
float: left;
clear: left;
width: 300px;
margin: 15px;
  }
#red .ui-slider-range { background: #ef2929; }
```

### HTML:

```
<body >
   <div id="red"></div>
   <div id="va"></div>
 </body>
```

### JS JQUERY:

```
function getval()
{
document.getElementById("va").innerHTML = $( "#red" ).slider( "option",     "value" );
 }

$(function() {
$( "#red").slider({
  orientation: "horizontal",
  range: "min",
  max: 100,
  value: 10,
  slide : getval 
});
});
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6h49upte/

Also refer to the JQuery Slider API and examples its easy to implement. Check out the supported version of Jquery too.

Comment: thank you so much for the suggestion. I used bootstrap slider as well as jquery sliders. But with their complicated javascript. i was unable to implement dynamic min and max value on them. I hope it will work simply.

Comment: @shoaib refer the JQuery API documentationfor slider it will help you control values too. upvote and accept thanks

Answer (score 0):

To my knowlege you can only do this in Internet Explorer:

```css
input[type="range"]::-ms-fill-lower {
  background: blue;
}
input[type="range"]::-ms-fill-upper {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<input type="range" min="10" max="100" step="1">
```

Comment: Thank you for suggestion. But Its useful in internet Explorer only. I used webkit instead of ms but its not working anywhere except IE

Comment: Sorry it is not possible in any other Browser but Internet Explorer, thats your answer right here, sorry 